# What is the need of cross tables in database?

Tags: mysql, backend, database-administration

I have been assigned to create the following tables 
[image: database design]

I want to know what is the use of SoftwareCategoryFeatureCross, SoftwareCategoryCross, SoftwareFeatureCross tables in the design. How should I manage these on the front end design.

Comment: why don't you ask the one who assigned that to you?  When you find out, please tell us, I'd be very curious to know what's the rationale behind such an insanely bizarre idea.

Comment: It seems highly implausible that someone would set such an assignment without first explaining one of the essential principles of an RDBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this is how it's designed.

- A software can have one or more categories
- A Software can have one or more features
- Each category can in turn have one or more features

As far as Front End design is concerned, you can show all the softwares in a tabular form, with capabilities to filter by features and/or categories (or tag each software record with multiple features/categories). Clicking on any particular row will show all the categories and features for that software (using `JOIN` query).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.